# Which Java E-COMMERCE platform should we use?

Tags: java, ecommerce, magento

Me and my colleague would like to build a marketplace with online stores. We have background in Java development and a little bit of UI.

We are considering the following options:

1. Writing the code from scratch using Java and Spring.
2. Konakart.
3. Ofbiz
4. Moqui

We are researching these options for a while now but fail to understand the pros and cons of each option.

Google trends comparison of the Java platformes that we found and Magento which is written in PHP :
https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0264f7v,%2Fm%2F0dlmggb,scipioerp,MOQUI,%2Fm%2F04065k0

Any information will help up, thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Why it must be Java?

Comment: We are experienced with writing Java applications, do you recommend using an other language ?

Comment: I recommend not chosing based on language. Your ultimate goal is to setup a website to sell stuff, not build a Java website. Focus on get a platform that does what you want, then learn its language, if you ever need to code for it. More often than not, you'll find ready-made sites and plugins will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we are looking to build a market place and not just one store.
Where can we start ? this is a new field for us ? the technologies i mentioned above are outdated ?